# Is it correct that the Instagram Location/Search endpoint does NOT support pagination?

Tags: api, instagram

I have read several postings about the fact that the Instagram API returns only 20 results at a time.  In many cases, people have suggested that all you need to do is to use the next URL which is returned in the pagination information.  I would be fine with that, but the JSON returned by

https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?

does not appear to have any pagination information.  I have seen a posting that says that /media/search does not support pagination.  I just wanted to confirm that the same is true for /locations/search.  Can anyone confirm?

And if this is correct, does anyone have any thoughts about how you can get a list of all Instagram events in a specific area, rather than just the first 20 or so?

Answer (score 9):

`/media/search` end point does not have pagination, but you can get next set of 20 pics by using url param `max_timestamp`, get the `created_time` of the last photo in api response and apply it as `max_timestamp` for next url call, it will return the next 20. Thats how I implemented here: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map

for `locations/search` end point, timestamp does not apply, you can change `distance` url param and get more results: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/places

Comment: @user2205101 this is absolutely the correct answer. Why don't you accept it, or at least add some comment ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is 100% true at this point, but it seems like the api endpoint `/locations/search` is capped at returning 20 distinct locations regardless of the `?distance={meters}` query param. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: @Dalvik: Sorry for not responding sooner.  My question was specifically about the locations/search query, so the beginning of the answer from krisrak does not really help me.  And the second part of the answer, regarding locations/search, doesn't seem to work, at least for me.  I don't get any change in results when changing the distance parameter.  I only see 33 results no matter what I do (unless the total number of available results is <33.  So I guess I should say that I only see <=33 results no matter what I do.)