# Using latitude and longitude in Instagram API for get more than 20 images

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am writing PHP code to get Instagram images on behalf of latitude and longitude in API. But all time I am getting only 20 images. Can any body help me to sort out this issue?

Here is the code:

```
 $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search');
 $client->setParameterGet('client_id', $CLIENT_ID);
 $client->setParameterGet('lat', $_POST['lat']);
 $client->setParameterGet('lng', $_POST['long']);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum number of requests for Instagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322028/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-requests-for-instagram). In short: The instagram API only returns 20 pictures, but then you can make another request to get more pictures. Use their pagination. The linked duplicate will tell you how. This was simply found by Googling "*instagram api 20 results*".

Comment: I want to make only one request and need to get more than 20 picture from the instagram

Comment: Then make multiple requests by using paging. You need to code this. Unless you get Instagram to change their Api, then this is how it works.

Comment: Paging concept is not available on the search by lat , long , distance in the instagram api .

Comment: Can you provide me some apis for this please

Comment: [Found by Googling "instagram media search pagination"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588273/is-it-correct-that-the-instagram-location-search-endpoint-does-not-support-pagin).

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593420/423089

- get the `created_time` of the last photo in api response.
- use the value as `max_timestamp=` in url param and make API call, this will give u next 20 images.

Here is working example: http://gramfeed.com/instagram/map