# Instagram historical data when searching by longitude and latitude

Tags: instagram

I want to extract pictures going back one year on Instagram from the following location: 53.740945, -0.34011617.

I have the following url:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=53.740945&lng=-0.34011617&access_token= INSERT ACCESS TOKEN

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Look into the requests or urllib libraries. Then come back with a more precise question.

Comment: Urr well I've been going through the Instagram documentation and I have no come across a "since" or "until" endpoint that would let me specify dates, Is there anyway I could specify dates in the api at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `max_timestamp` url param to get more posts beyond the 20 post u get with API call. Here is link to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593420/423089

Here is an implementation for location search with time: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map